# How to get the raw request body in an asp.NET 3.5 WCF Web Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I've been required to develop a C# rest api that needs to log (in a database table) every single request to any defined route. Every log needs to record the request body, url, response body and status (Pending, Success or Error)

After a lot of internet research, I found the example below, which is the closest to what I need, but it gives me the data in XML format, I need the original format, which is Json.

```
var payload = System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()
```

**Update - Solution**

After talking to [vendettamit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881798/vendettamit), I got the solution below, which I think is worth sharing here:

This is my service:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using AdvLinkForWebService.BusinessRules;
using AdvLinkForWebService.JsonModel;

namespace AdvLinkForWebService
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService{

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                   UriTemplate = "gaterequest/{param}")]
        ReturnMessage PostgateRequest(JsonData data, string param);

    }

    public class Service : IService
    {
        // Any new Rout will follow this template:
        public ReturnMessage PostgateRequest(JsonData data, string param)
        {

            // This is the return value
            var ret = new ReturnMessage();

            try {

                // Business Rules resides inside gateBusinessRules
                var businessRuleHandler = new gateBusinessRules();
                businessRuleHandler.DoPost(data, param);

                ret.type = true;
                ret.message = "OK";

                // Log success, if nothing wrong had happened
                Utils.logSuccess();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log exception, if something wrong had happened
                ret.type = false;
                ret.message = "NOK: " + e.Message;
                Utils.logException(e.ToString());
            }
            return ret;
        }


    }
}
```

This is my Utils class, that encapsulates log operations:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace AdvLinkForWebService
{

    public class Utils
    {

        public static string DB_CONNECTION_STRING = "Data Source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;User Id=XXX;Password=XXX";

        public static int logOperation(string type, string payload){

            var url = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.OriginalString;
            var method = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Method;
            var userAgent = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UserAgent;

            int key = 0;

            // Do stuff to insert url, method, user agent and request payload in the database
            // the generated key from the insertion will be returned as the key variable

            return key;

        }

        public static void logResponse(int resCode, string resPayload)
        {

            int logId =  (int) System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Properties["logID"];

            // Do stuff to update the log record in the database based on the ID
            // This method updates response code and response payload
        }

        public static void logSuccess()
        {

            int logId =  (int) System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Properties["logID"];

            // Do stuff to update the log record in the database based on the ID
            // This method just updates log status to success
        }

        public static void logException(string error)
        {
            WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
            ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

            int logId =  (int) System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Properties["logID"];

            // Do stuff to update the log record in the database based on the ID
            // This method just updates log status to error and log the error message
        }


        public Utils()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class responsible to log the raw Json from the request and response:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace AdvLinkForWebService.MessageInspector
{
    public class IncomingMessageLogger : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {

        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            // Set up the message and stuff
            Uri requestUri = request.Headers.To;
            HttpRequestMessageProperty httpReq = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlDictionaryWriter writer = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(ms);
            request.WriteMessage(writer);
            writer.Flush();

            // Log the message in the Database
            string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            var logID = Utils.logOperation("I", messageBody);

            // Reinitialize readers and stuff
            ms.Position = 0;
            XmlDictionaryReader reader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(ms, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
            Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, request.Version);

            // Put the ID generated at insertion time in a property
            // in order to use it over again to update the log record
            // with the response payload and, OK or error status
            request.Properties.Add("logID", logID);
            newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(request.Properties);

            request = newMessage;
            return requestUri;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {           
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlDictionaryWriter writer = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(ms);
            reply.WriteMessage(writer);
            writer.Flush();

            // Log the response in the Database         
            HttpResponseMessageProperty prop = (HttpResponseMessageProperty) reply.Properties["httpResponse"];
            int statusCode = (int) prop.StatusCode;
            string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            Utils.logResponse(statusCode, messageBody);

            // Reinitialize readers and stuff
            ms.Position = 0;
            XmlDictionaryReader reader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(ms, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
            Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, reply.Version);
            newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(reply.Properties);
            reply = newMessage;

        }

    }

    public class InsepctMessageBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new IncomingMessageLogger());
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }
    }

    public class InspectMessageBehaviorExtension : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get { return typeof(InsepctMessageBehavior); }
        }

        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new InsepctMessageBehavior();
        }
    }

}
```

And finally, this is the xml configuration necessary in order to get it all working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="AdvLinkForWebService.Service">
                <endpoint address=""
                          binding="webHttpBinding"
                          contract="AdvLinkForWebService.IService"
                          behaviorConfiguration="defaultWebHttpBehavior"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>             
                <behavior name="defaultWebHttpBehavior">
                    <inspectMessageBehavior/>
                    <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <extensions>
            <behaviorExtensions>
                <add name="inspectMessageBehavior"
                     type="AdvLinkForWebService.MessageInspector.InspectMessageBehaviorExtension, AdvLinkForWebService"/>
            </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: check out my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33349912/881798) for capturing raw data in WCF Rest API.

Comment: vendettamit, I had already tried it, but my AfterReceiveRequest method was not being called. Maybe I missed a xml configuration (the app is going to be deployed on IIS). I'm going to edit my question, including web.config and service.svc, could you check what I missed ?

Comment: Post your configuration as well. Let see what is missed.

Comment: Posted, as you can see, it's very minimalistic because it's not a VisualStudio project, it's a SharpDevelop project.

Comment: I don't see the MessageInspector behavior being injected anywhere in the configuration. This is why your AfterReceiveRequest is not getting called.

Comment: vendettamit, you jus rock, probably i misspelled a namespace name or whatever on the xml configuration the first time i tried. Thank you.

Comment: Answer: [answer from vendettamit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343908/handle-json-request-data-in-wcf-rest-service-post-method/33349912#33349912)

Comment: Shall I add it to answer?

Comment: yes please, this is the answer, but I have another problem, this one probably for another question, how can I share an int value between the AfterReceiveRequest method and my operation PostgateRequest? That's because I'm logging every single request in a database table, it generates an ID when the record is inserted at AfterReceiveRequest, and I have to update the status of the log to Success or Error, depending on what happened at PostgateRequest, and for that, I have to use de ID generated at the time of insertion.

Comment: What is the JsonData type that you use in the solution?

Comment: @UberSchnoz, the only thing I've set up was the parameters RequestFormat and ResponseFormat at the WebInvoke decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a custom IDispatchMessageInspector to capture raw request in method AfterReceiveRequest see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33349912/881798).

**Update(for recent comment):**

Adressing your recent comment, You can modify the Message content to add additional information like in your case an ID; If you look at the code in sample inside the method MessageString it is creating a new message writer based on the type of WebContent received. If it's Json then JsonReader will be used. Just add your information in Message body string like below:

```
 string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
 messageBody = messageBody.Insert(<correct index position>, "<your new ID>");

 ms.Position = 0;
 XmlDictionaryReader reader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(new StringReader(messageBody), XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);

 Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, message.Version);
```

Note: This strategy would require to have additional 'ID' in your `JsonData` class. So that the value gets derserialized. But this is not the only way to achieve it. Probably when you ask another question put all scenarios.

Comment: It's a good idea to change the message body, but the method JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader is not accepting a StringReader as it's first parameter, it's supposed to be a Stream.

Comment: I got this working. It's not necessary to change the request content anymore, instead I add a property to the request. I'm going to updtate my question with these changes. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped you moving forward!! :)

Comment: vendettamit, could you please check my  [new question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545824/wcf-cannot-create-custom-endpointbehavior-only-in-prod-environment)

Answer (score 0):

You set your method to receive (Invoke) json message, and you can also set it to return json as response adding WebGet to your operation:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                   UriTemplate = "gaterequest/{param}")]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        ReturnMessage PostgateRequest(JsonData data, string param);
```

Hope it helps