# WCF cannot create custom endpointbehavior only in PROD environment

Tags: web-services, rest, endpointbehavior

I have a WCF rest web service. Everything works fine on my development environment (#develop using IIS express), but i get the following error on my production evironment:

> Server Error in '/Services' Application.
>       --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.serviceModel/behaviors: Extension element 'inspectMessageBehavior' cannot be added to this element.  Verify that the extension is registered in the extension collection at system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions.
Parameter name: element

Source Error: 


Line 16:            </service>
Line 17:        </services>
Line 18:        <behaviors>
Line 19:            <endpointBehaviors>
Line 20:                <behavior name="webHttp">


Source File: C:\Otimis\AdvLinkForWebService\services\web.config    Line: 18 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

This is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="AdvLinkForWebService.inbound">
                <endpoint address=""
                          binding="webHttpBinding"
                          contract="AdvLinkForWebService.Iinbound"
                          behaviorConfiguration="defaultWebHttpBehavior"/>
            </service>
            <service name="AdvLinkForWebService.config">
                <endpoint address=""
                          binding="webHttpBinding"
                          contract="AdvLinkForWebService.Iconfig"
                          behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="webHttp">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
                <behavior name="defaultWebHttpBehavior">
                    <inspectMessageBehavior/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <extensions>
            <behaviorExtensions>
                <add name="inspectMessageBehavior"
                     type="AdvLinkForWebService.MessageInspector.InspectMessageBehaviorExtension, AdvLinkForWebService"/>
            </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376319/how-to-get-the-raw-request-body-in-an-asp-net-3-5-wcf-web-service/33413954#comment54631579_33413954) one

Comment: vendettamit, could you please take a look?

Comment: Everythink look ok! The only thing I can see is you have `DefaultWebHttpBehavior` and `webHttp` behavior as two separate behaviors. `WebHttp` behavior is actually the one which makes WCF a REST service. So you have to define `WebHttp` in `defaultWebHttpBehavior` too.

Comment: Also make sure the type definition is correct `AdvLinkForWebService.MessageInspector.InspectMessageBehaviorExtension, AdvLinkForWebService` Because the error says it can't find the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run properly in my production evironment, it was necessary to specify the version, culture and key for inspectMessageBehavior. Ended up with the following configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <extensions>
            <behaviorExtensions>
                <add name="inspectMessageBehavior"
                     type="AdvLinkForWebService.MessageInspector.InspectMessageBehaviorExtension, AdvLinkForWebService, Version=1.0.5791.17758, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
            </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="defaultWebHttpBehavior">
                    <webHttp/>
                    <inspectMessageBehavior/>
                </behavior>
                <behavior name="webHttp">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service name="AdvLinkForWebService.inbound">
                <endpoint address=""
                          binding="webHttpBinding"
                          contract="AdvLinkForWebService.Iinbound"
                          behaviorConfiguration="defaultWebHttpBehavior"/>
            </service>
            <service name="AdvLinkForWebService.config">
                <endpoint address=""
                          binding="webHttpBinding"
                          contract="AdvLinkForWebService.Iconfig"
                          behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I don't know exactly how the version number is generated, even if it can be controlled, but I obtained it with the following command:

```
typeof(InspectMessageBehaviorExtension).AssemblyQualifiedName
```